# cloud_firestore/permission-denied The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am try to SignUp with google account to firebase and save the data on the firestore
then that error shown to me

[cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.
that my code

```
void googleSignInMethod() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
        await googleUser!.authentication;
    print(googleUser);

    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
      accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    );

    await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential).then((user) {
      Get.offAll(Country());
      saveUser(user);
    });
  }
```

and that the code where I save data to the firestore

```
void saveUser(UserCredential user) async {
    await FireStoreUser().addUserToFireStore(UserModel(
      email: '${user.user!.email}',
      name: name ?? '${user.user!.displayName}',
      pic: '',
      userId: user.user!.uid,
    ));
  }
```

this one where I set and reseve it form firestore

```
class FireStoreUser {
  final CollectionReference _userCollectionRef =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users');

  Future<void> addUserToFireStore(UserModel userModel) async {
    return await _userCollectionRef
        .doc(userModel.userId)
        .set(userModel.toJson());
  }
}
```

Comment: I know where is the error in fireStore there is an Rules go there rules_version = '1';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}  u just change  allow read, write: if false; to  allow read, write: if true;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know where is the error in fireStore there is an Rules go there

```
rules_version = '1';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

u just change `allow read, write: if false;` to `allow read, write: if true;`

Comment: Take into account that if you set the rules like this, the document can be read or write by everyone, this should only be used on dev environment, do NOT USE this solution if you are in production.

Answer (score 2):

Can you share your Firestore Rules with us;

[https://console.firebase.google.com/project/[YourAppName]/firestore/rules](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/%5BYourAppName%5D/firestore/rules)

The following rule will allow **authenticated users** *write* and *read* Firestore data.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
 match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
  }
 }
}
```